# Get an 'unshifted' punctuation mark after pressing a key with shift

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm binding keystroke events to methods in Tkinter, separate for regular and shift-key strokes (for easier handling). However in my shift-key event method I really need to get an event.char as if the key was pressed without shift, and then handle the actual modifier in a different way. Calling lower() on a string created from event.char does work for letters, it doesn't for punctuation marks though, which is the main issue, since an operation happening later doesn't recognize '!' - it expects 'shift'+'1'.

Is there any way to accomplish that, other than creating a huge dictionary of 'uppercase' punctuation and their 'lowercase' relatives? The event.keycode is the same for both lower and uppercase characters, maybe somehow reversing that to get a character would work? But then again, the only way I can think of is querying a dictionary of all keycodes (that's available somewhere on the Internet afaik), and I really would rather not have to operate on big dictionaries that could slow the entire process down.

Comment: Don't forget that there isn't a single standard keyboard layout. There are many, and they have different punctuation marks in different places.  For example, you might think you "know" what shift + comma means, but that's keyboard layout-dependent. Also, if you're afraid of "huge" dictionaries because of potential performance reasons, don't be. The numbers of entries you're talking about are not really huge, and dictionaries are designed to handle lots of entries.

Comment: Yeah, this seems really non-portable based upon what keyboard layout the user happens to have.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're trying to do isn't possible. Deep under the covers, in Tcl/Tk land, the keyboard-layout-specific key numbers get converted in platform-specific ways to the `%k`/`keysym` value, which is all that Tkinter has access to, and therefore all you have access to in your code. You can at least guess that Shift was involved (by seeing a shift key event with no corresponding release before the key event you're looking at…), but that still doesn't tell you how to undo it.

Comment: If you really need to do this, does it really need to be in Tkinter? Some of the other GUI libraries give you more detailed access to event information. Alternatively, can you write platform-specific code for each platform you care about that hooks in before Tk gets the events and stores the info for you to get later?

Comment: Given that the average keyboard has about 100 keys, most of which are either letters or modifiers, how big of a dictionary would you really need? Ten entries? Twenty? Even for a dictionary with hundreds of entries, it wouldn't slow down performance to any appreciable degree.